# VS Code, User Config for "Place Open Brace On New Line" not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Having a weird issue with my user settings in VS Code.

I am learning node.js, and I want to format curly braces as such:

```
if (something) 
{
    //do something
}
```

instead of:

```
if (something) {
    //do something
}
```

I tried changing the following options in File > Preferences > User Settings, as well as Workspace settings:

```
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true
```

These seemed to do nothing at all, when I press enter inside {}, it just opens the braces like in the second example.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Same issue here, did you figure anything out yet? Also, when I use the Typescript build task to convert it to javascript, it also replaces all newline braces with braces that start on the same line.

Comment: Really sorry about the late response, didn't log on for a while. I just ended up getting used to the convention, it turn's out this is just the standard for everything in JavaScript. Having used it for a while now, I still prefer having them on separate lines, but I got very used to reading JS like this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Did you invoke the Format Document action?